# get the details inside PDF Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, itext

Got this series of PDFs that i need to get all the details inside. I can already get some text details using iTextsharp but problem is, some PDF have images and that image contain some details.

So is it possible i can get those images and its details inside? As sample image below i want to get the word "head eye", "body square", and "footer square". I don't need the 'drawing' what i need is the word/s inside the image.

If there's some API/library which i can use in my .Net C# application it will be great. Thanks![image]

Comment: Ate those images bitmap images and is the writing part of that image? In that case you have to apply OCR to the images which you can extract using iTextSharp. Otherwise you should succeed using iTextSharp Text extraction capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If the text you are trying to read out is on the image or mixed, you could use [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to rasterize PDF (convert pdf page to image) and then use [**Tesseract**](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to read the text out from the parts of that image.

Since you want to do this via .NET (C#), you can get .NET wrappers for both components from here:

**Ghostscript.NET**: **http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com**

**tesseract-ocr .net:** **https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/**